# How to make session time out from client side

Tags: iphone, web-services

I need to test a client app on IPhone which connect to a WebServices.
This connection time out is check once/day at 6am.
So, we can only test "time-out" case only once/day.
I want to test more time/day. But I can not change on Web Service because of no authentication.

There a solution to use a proxy server to catch package, change session ID and send to test server. But I don't know how to do it?
Can anyone help me?
Any other solution?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For the proxy solution you suggest, I recommend [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com). In Charles you can [rewrite](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/tools/rewrite/) both the request and the response from the server.

> The Rewrite tool enables you to create rules that modify requests and responses as they pass through Charles. Rules such as adding or changing a header or search and replace some text in the response body.